# iCarousel carouselCurrentItemIndexDidChange method giving wrong index

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, icarousel

I am using `iCarousel` for displaying images in Rotary flow.
I am calling this method :

```
-(void)carouselCurrentItemIndexDidChange:(iCarousel *)carousel
```

for changing image during swipe.
Now initially when i come to my view controller this method is getting called and it is giving me **-1 Current index instead of 0**. `(and because of this app crash with beyond bounds for empty array)`.
Can anyone help me out!

Answer (score 0):

try this

**Swift 3.0**

```
  func carouselCurrentItemIndexDidChange(_ carousel: iCarousel) {
        print(carousel.currentItemIndex)
  }
```

**ObjectiveC**

```
-(void)carouselCurrentItemIndexDidChange:(iCarousel *)carousel {
       NSLog(@"%d",carousel.currentItemIndex)
}
```

Comment: i did the same and i am getting wrong index. Why i am getting wrong index, for that i needed help

Comment: Please, show me your carousel DataSource & Delegate Methods